# How do vampires know how they look like?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

According to the vampire section in the MM (p. 295) and to 99% of any vampire trivia, vampires don't cast shadows or reflections.

Can a vampire be obsessed with his own appearance if he never saw how he looks like ? (assuming he didn't retain any memories of his former life).

I'm pretty sure Strahd is quite concerned about his appearance, although I don't have the Curse of Strahd adventure handy to confirm that. But Strahd *does* remember his former life.. so I don't know.

Comment: Don't answer in comments.

Comment: I have no experience in dnd5e and the question is on hold, but there are more possibilities than mirrors. Illusions come to my mind quite fast. "Ask" someone to create an illusion or a statue (Form stone) of you. Maybe make it into a magic item you can activate at will. That's what my GM did for a noble. The illusion was obvious, so it brought no advantage to our power gamer.